# Derivatives of two ODE marching algorithms in series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In a previous post of mine ([Derivative of an ODE marching algorithm such as Euler or Runge Kutta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119506/derivative-of-an-ode-marching-algorithm-such-as-euler-or-runge-kutta)) @LutzL showed how to obtain $V=\frac{\partial P_n}{\partial Q}$ and $W=\frac{\partial P_n}{\partial P_0}$ where \begin{align}
P'&=f(x,P,Q)\\
V'&=f_P·V+f_Q\\
W'&=f_P·W
\end{align}
by integrating all three differential equations at the same time from distance $x=0$ to $x=L$.  $P'=\frac{dP}{dx}$, $V'=\frac{dV}{dx}$ and $W'=\frac{dW}{dx}$. The initial conditions at the start are $P=P_0$, $V=0$ and $W=1$.  This works fine.

I have a further question.  These equations pertain to a pipe where $P_0$ is the pressure at the source and let $P_1$ be the pressure at the sink, and flowrate = $Q$.  So from the above equations I can calculate $P_1$, $\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial Q}$ and $\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial P_0}$.

Now suppose I have another pipe tacked onto the end of this pipe and I need to find $\frac{\partial P_2}{\partial Q}$ and $\frac{\partial P_2}{\partial P_0}$. ie. derivatives for the whole pipe (both sections together).

I can solve the second pipe in the same way, giving $P_2$, $\frac{\partial P_2}{\partial Q}$ and $\frac{\partial P_2}{\partial P_1}$, assuming I use the correct initial conditions at $P=P_1$.  Would these be $P=P_1$, $V=\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial Q}$ and $W=1$ ?  Or should the latter be $W=\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial P_0}$ ?

This appears to give $\frac{\partial P_2}{\partial Q}$.  However how do I get $\frac{\partial P_2}{\partial P_0}$ ?  Does it equal $\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial P_0} · \frac{\partial P_2}{\partial P_1}$ ?

Comment: Yes to all your observations. You need to apply the chain rule, either by setting the initial condition at the middle point to the previous derivative to ensure continuity or by setting that initial value to unity and multiplying the result as in your last formula.